# safe casting in C

Tags: c, casting

hello everyone I have this snippet of the code:

```
void writer(void* param){
    if(NULL == param){
        return;
    }
    param = (param_t*)param;
...
}
```

is it safe code, or not, param is from type param_t*, but I'm sick doing every time casting when I use it in function, do Somebody have another elegant solution? thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a strange no-op.

When you define the function you say param is of type `void*`.
Then, with the cast, you explicitly convert it to `param_t*`
And the compiler implicitly converts that `param_t*` to `void*` with the assignment.

You need another variable

```
void writer(void *param) {
    param_t *internal_param;

    if (NULL == param) return;
    internal_param = param;
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to cast a void* to another pointer type in C.

So just do:

```
void writer(void* param){
   param_t *myparam;
    if(NULL == param){
        return;
    }
    myparam = param;
...
}
```

(But why are you using a void* for the argument anyway?)

Answer (score 2):

The (implicit) cast in the assignment is safe even if the pointer value is NULL, so there's no need to defer it. You could do this:

```
void writer(void* param)
{
  param_t* myparam = param;

  if (myparam == NULL)
    return;

  ...
}
```

Comment: I'd just use "conversion" (possibly with the "implicit") there: a "cast" is an "explicit conversion" :)

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is to avoid using `void *` and use `param_t *` instead, as in:

```
void writer(param_t * param)
{
  if (param == NULL)
  {
    return;
  }

  ...
}
```

You could drop the NULL test if you *know* that it's never called with a NULL pointer. Alternatively, you could replace it with `assert(param != NULL)`.

Comment: I suspect OP is following a required function signature for some API, e.g. for a thread start function. Thus changing the argument type is not possible.